# How to view sent and received packets in OSX like in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, macos, networking

When I was on Windows XP I remember if you brought up the network information there would be a part of the window that would say packets sent and received (I would supply a screenshot, but I cannot).

I am curious if in OS X there is anyway to see the how many packets have been sent and received since the network connection was started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Activity Monitor` (in Applications > Utilities). Click on the `Network` subtab at the bottom of the main screen.

Comment: I knew it was something so simple!  I just didn't know where to look!